# Create a dataframe with tickers as rows and a for loop as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, for-loop

I have a dataframe `close` consists of close price (with some calculations beforehand) of some stocks, and I want to create a dataframe (with empty entries or random numbers) such that the row names are the tickers of the `close` and column names are from 10 to 300 with a step size 10. ie. 10,20,30,40,50...

**I want to create this df in order to use a for loop to fill in all the entries.**

The df `close` I have is like below:

```
                 Close                                                    \
ticker            AAPL        AMD        BIDU        GOOGL          IXIC   
Date                                                                       
2011-06-01   12.339643   8.370000  132.470001   263.063049   2769.189941   
2011-06-02   12.360714   8.240000  138.490005   264.294281   2773.310059   
2011-06-03   12.265714   7.970000  133.210007   261.801788   2732.780029   
2011-06-06   12.072857   7.800000  126.970001   260.790802   2702.560059   
2011-06-07   11.858571   7.710000  124.820000   259.774780   2701.560059 
......
```

I tried to check if I firstly create this dataframe correctly as below:

```
rows = close.iloc[0]
columns = [[i] for i in range(10,300,10)]
print(pd.DataFrame(rows, columns))
```

But what I got is:

```
2011-06-01
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190 200 210 220 230 240 250 260 270 280 290 NaN
```

After this, I would use something like

```
percent = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns)
for i in range(10, 300, 10):
    myerror = myfunction(close, i) # myfunction is a function defined beforehand
    extreme = myerror > 0.1 
    percent.iloc[:,i] = extreme.mean()
```

To be specific, for `i=10`, my `extreme.mean()` is something like:

```
                             ticker
Absolute Error (Volatility)  AAPL      0.420
                             AMD       0.724
                             BIDU      0.552
                             GOOGL     0.316
                             IXIC      0.176
                             MSFT      0.320
                             NDXT      0.228
                             NVDA      0.552
                             NXPI      0.476
                             QCOM      0.468
                             SWKS      0.560
                             TXN       0.332
dtype: float64
```

But if I tried this way, I got:

```
IndexError: iloc cannot enlarge its target object
```

How shall I create this df first? Or do I even need to create this df first?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will approach it:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""ticker_Date            AAPL        AMD        BIDU        GOOGL          IXIC   
2011-06-01   12.339643   8.370000  132.470001   263.063049   2769.189941   
2011-06-02   12.360714   8.240000  138.490005   264.294281   2773.310059   
2011-06-03   12.265714   7.970000  133.210007   261.801788   2732.780029   
2011-06-06   12.072857   7.800000  126.970001   260.790802   2702.560059   
2011-06-07   11.858571   7.710000  124.820000   259.774780   2701.560059 """), sep="\s+", index_col=0)

col_names = [f"col_{i}" for i in range(10, 300, 10)]
# generate random data
data = np.random.random((df.shape[1], len(col_names)))
# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names, index=df.columns.values)
df.head()
```

This will generate:

```
        col_10  col_20  col_30  col_40  col_50  col_60  col_70  col_80  col_90  col_100 ... col_200 col_210 col_220 col_230 col_240 col_250 col_260 col_270 col_280 col_290
AAPL    0.758983    0.990241    0.804344    0.143388    0.987025    0.402098    0.814308    0.302948    0.551587    0.107503    ... 0.270523    0.813130    0.354939    0.594897    0.711924    0.574312    0.124053    0.586718    0.182854    0.430028
AMD     0.280330    0.540498    0.958757    0.779778    0.988756    0.877748    0.083683    0.935331    0.601838    0.998863    ... 0.426469    0.459916    0.458180    0.047625    0.234591    0.831229    0.975838    0.277486    0.663604    0.773614
BIDU    0.488226    0.792466    0.488340    0.639612    0.829161    0.459805    0.619539    0.614297    0.337481    0.009500    ... 0.049147    0.452581    0.230441    0.943240    0.587269    0.703462    0.528252    0.099104    0.510057    0.151219
GOOGL   0.332762    0.135621    0.653414    0.955116    0.341629    0.213716    0.308320    0.982095    0.762138    0.532052    ... 0.095432    0.908001    0.077070    0.413706    0.036768    0.481697    0.092373    0.016260    0.394339    0.042559
IXIC    0.358842    0.653332    0.994692    0.863552    0.307594    0.269833    0.972357    0.520336    0.124850    0.907647    ... 0.189050    0.664955    0.167708    0.333537    0.295740    0.093228    0.762875    0.779000    0.316752    0.687238
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But I have made some calculation on the df `close` beforehand. And when I read the files, I used `pd.concat([read_file(f) for f in glob('*.csv')]).set_index(['Date','ticker'])[['Close']].unstack()`. And now if I use your code without the `index=df.columns.values`, I got what you generated except that my row name is `0,1,2,3,4`. Can I ask how should I change the row name used the tickers?

Comment: I think you are calling `index` as row name. you can just `df.index=val` where `val` is a `iterable` like `list` with the desired `index` values.

Comment: do you mean the `index` of my `close`? But my `close.index` are the `Date`..